# Is there any tool which rewrites C++ for-loops to stl-algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl, static-analysis

In C# *Resharper* manages to rewrite old-school for loops to *LINQ* expressions. Is there any tool which manages to do pretty much the same in C++, with the difference it rewrites for-loops to utilize stl-algorithms where plausable?

Comment: That would be too good to be true.

Comment: hmm, seems I might have a buisness idea then =)

Comment: C++ is too hard to parse for any such tool to work reliably.

Comment: @AlexandreC. That sounds like a challenge.

Comment: It would also be about the right time.... now that we have C++11 with lambda's, there will be much more code that could be rewritten in terms of stl algorithms..

Comment: @ViktorSehr: I can see libclang being useful here.

Comment: C++ algorithms are sooo flexible with the `_if` versions and predicates that it could be very hard to do this.

Comment: @MarkB: Que? I don't want to rewrite algorithms to for-loops

Comment: @ViktorSehr I believe Mark meant that knowing which combination of algorithm and predicate (or lambda) to use would be very hard to determine automatically.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I mean that the amount of work necessary to be put into such a tool is probably not worth the reward.

Comment: I'd settle for a tool which replaces `for(T::iterator it = c.begin(); it < c.end(); ++it) x(*it)` with `for(auto& t : c) x(t)`.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an intern :)

Comment: @Rob: at minimum I'd think you'd want to use a variable in the condition rather than 'end()' as the way it is written now the compiler needs to determine if `end()` changes between calls.

Comment: @AlexanderC. When building a tool like this it may cost you a lot of time (or whoever does it) but it may save a lot of other people's time. I wouldn't necessarily rewrite the code but suggesting rewrites may be goid enough (and if they turn out to be OK maybe start rewriting the code at some point).

Comment: @AlexandreC. C++ is hard to parse, but compilers do it and so do other tools. See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need a [Program Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) system such as [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrondEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).

DMS parses code into ASTs, enable various analyses to be run, can apply source-to-source transformations conditioned on the analyses, and can regenerate source code from the transformed ASTs.

In one of the comments, Rob sez:

> I'd settle for a tool which replaces for(T::iterator it = c.begin(); it < c.end(); ++it) x(*it) with for(auto& t : c) x(t).

That's pretty easy to write with DMS:

```
 rule robs_rule(T:IDENTIFIER, it:IDENTIFIER, 
                c:IDENTIFIER, x: IDENTIFIER)
     :statement->statement
 = " for(\T::iterator \it = \c.begin(); \it < \c.end(); ++\it) \x(*\it)"
   =>  "for(auto& \t : \c) \x(\t)";
```

While the rule appears to be text, it is actually description of an AST to AST rewrite; it is parsed with DMS C++ front end.   Consequently matches are reliable and not based on string hacking. (The fact the \c occurs twice in the pattern forces both to be identical).

In practice, you'll want a lot of rules to cover the case you care about, and you'll likely want to generalize them more, such as applying  *\it => \it in a subsidiary statement.   It will also be useful to harness various kinds of flow analysis to support the transformations.  At this point DMS offers control flow analysis but not yet data flow analysis for C++.

At present, these kinds of tasks are possible but not necessarily easy to write with DMS.  It has been used to carry out massive C++ architecture reshaping; check the bibliography at the web site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may be that there is no such tool out there (yet). In the meantime you could have a look at [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page). This is a tool for static code analysis. It does a fairly good job on the generic side, but it also allows you to define your own ruleset. This might bring you actually close to the C# Resharper solution.